Android Studio - Virtual Device creation stuck on "Select System Image" stage
I'm using Android Studio version 2021.3.1. When trying to create a new virtual device, I'm stuck on the select image screen. Even after selecting and downloading the image, clicking the "next" button does not take me to the next step of the configuration process, even though the button itself is enabled, as shown on the image.
Image of the device creation screen
I've tried selecting different system images and reinstalling the Android SDK through the SDK Manager. I would appreciate it if someone who has gone through this could help me out.

The virtual device manager should be part of Android Studio which is in your case a pretty outdated version. May be the selected image is too new for your system. I would recommend to update to a newer Android Studio version.

I actually need to use that version because is the last one compatible with the Flutter version the project I'm working on uses. But my other colleague uses this same version without a problem on the same image, so it should be working fine. I'll try some older image anyway to check out if that could be the issue.

Then I would try to install a recent Android Studio in parallel to the old one and use it to download and create the virtual device. Hopefully once the virtual device has been set-up it will also work in the old Android Studio version.

use the genymotion instead of simulator
